# Is there a Python library to perform hierarchical clustering on a 3 dimensional array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'm looking for a library in Python to perform hierarchical clustering on a (365-days, 24-hours, 8-time series) array. I want to find N representative days (N-days,24-hours, 8-time series), common for the 8 time series. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know what you really want to do but what with `pandas.DataFrame` or `numpy.array`?

Comment: Agglomerative Clustering is available, but works only for 2-D arrays. It cannot handle 3-D arrays.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering